# is there any way to dyamically change the color of default theme

Tags: android, styles, themes

Received color code from api on splash screen, now i want to replace my theme color to  which i received from backend to whole application. Is it possible?  Searched but didn't get any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You could save that color to DataStore or SharedPreferences and then use it programmatically in onCreate before setting content in each activity.